# How to find who has checked in last on VSS?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

Is there any way to know about the user who has checked in last items on VSS?
We've shared folder on our server(other than VSS server) where we keep internal project copies. But recently someone has replaced it with some invalid copy. As there isn;t any way of finding who has done this job, I looked for some trace of information that may help in finding the user who has done this; and I found VSS control meta data file in project folder?
It has following piece of information:

""
{
"FILE_VERSION" = "9237"
"ENLISTMENT_CHOICE" = "NEVER"
"PROJECT_FILE_RELATIVE_PATH" = ""
"NUMBER_OF_EXCLUDED_FILES" = "0"
"ORIGINAL_PROJECT_FILE_PATH" = ""
"NUMBER_OF_NESTED_PROJECTS" = "0"
"SOURCE_CONTROL_SETTINGS_PROVIDER" = "PROVIDER"
}

Is this of any help for tracing out the same version on VSS?

thanks in advance,
Kapil

Answer (score 0):

Or look into the journal.txt in your vss database folder